# Expand clickable area of anchor without affecting position with CSS

Tags: css

In a mobile web application I have recently created there are many anchor tags used throughout. The anchor tags by default have a clickable area that is purely surrounding the text. I am looking to try and expand this area without affecting the position of the anchor tag at all.

[image]

The black border shows the current clickable area and the red border shows the clickable area I would much prefer. The first thing you think of is to add padding, but this moves the tag which is the whole reason what I'm asking is a problem. How can I expand the clickable area of all the anchor tags in the application without affecting their positions?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use an absolute positionned  pseudo element to increase space where a link stands.
[**basic DEMO**](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/gotHK/):

```
a {
  display:inline-block;
  position:relative;
  border:solid;
}
a:before {
  content:'';
  position:absolute;
  top:-1em;
  left:-1em;
  right:-1em;
  bottom:-1em;
  border:solid red;
}
```

This a technique that can be usefull for menus that close too easily because submenu is too much on the edge.